# Extract a paragraph from a text file using batch and store it into a sql table

Tags: sql, bash

Im having a text file and hope to just extract one short sentence from the file and store it in to sql using batch. I am new to bash and does not know do i need to start it. Extract it with /f function or write function and store into a variable and insert the variable into sql table?

Comment: Use SSIS. Here's a tutorial. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n274c51-B3c

Answer (score 0):

You can simple `grep` the line into variable and than use this variable in your SQL syntax like below:

```
#!/bin/bash
variable=$(grep -c "some text" /some/path);
echo "INSERT INTO some_table (col1, col2) VALUES ('some_value', '$variable');" | mysql -uroot -ppass db_name;
```

Comment: Im sorry that i did not make it clear at first, what if the "some text" will be changing everyday, and I will need to run it to extract the "some text" every morning after it change. I just wan to extract the changes "some text" and upadte it to my database, to store the changes data.

Comment: Do you know how exactly it will change? Or you only know that some line was changed?

Comment: im actually trying retrieve the version of release, so for example: it will change according to the date. like yesterday's version is 22082017A, today version will be 23082017A.